# lede sdk compile error occur?

Tags: sdk, openwrt

when I compile sdk on lede, some errors occurd like this:

```
find: '/home/ascend/project/lede/build_dir/target-mips_24kc_musl-1.1.16/lede-sdk-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.4.0_musl-1.1.16.Linux-i686/staging_dir/host/usr/bin': No such file or directory
find: '/home/ascend/project/lede/build_dir/target-mips_24kc_musl-1.1.16/lede-sdk-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.4.0_musl-1.1.16.Linux-i686/staging_dir/host/usr/lib': No such file or directory
Makefile:76: recipe for target '/home/ascend/project/lede/bin/targets/ar71xx/generic/lede-sdk-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.4.0_musl-1.1.16.Linux-i686.tar.xz' failed
make[3]: [/home/ascend/project/lede/bin/targets/ar71xx/generic/lede-sdk-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.4.0_musl-1.1.16.Linux-i686.tar.xz] Error 123 (ignored)
```

But it compiled successfully and the image was made.

Some one have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some errors in the *format* of the file path, but the *path* is still correct. instead of using one back-slash between the folders, try using 2.
 If this doesn't work, just reply and then i will find another answer for you. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand. I compile lede on ubuntu, slash is used between the folders. As I understand it, the back-slashes are used between folders in windows, not linux.

Comment: what i meant was this: //, instead of this: /

Comment: Yeah, I will try it!